# Failed to start a project with react

Tags: reactjs

Starting a project with react.js, I create the project to write npm start a project I get the error, fuy to the address that says there, but I do not know how to fix it because what I ask help you the error is this: npm Err! Missing script: start.                 Npm Err! A complete log of this run can be found in npm Err! C:-Users-Sanvicente-Appdata-Roaming-npm-cache-_logs-2020-08-27t20_09_40_583z-debug.log.    (I'm starting with react)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i7uDT.png)

Comment: Could you share your source code? This error indicate that you didn't have a npm "start" script inside your `package.json`

Answer (score 1):

If you have created react app using `npx create-react-app <app_name>` command then you should find a `package.json` file inside the `<app_name>` folder. Ensure that that file has the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
```